# create a c# wrapper for rest based service

Tags: c#, rest

How does one go about creating a c# wrapper for rest based service.

I want to access the rest based API at 
Www.zomato.com
inside my Silverlight app.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side/7942315#7942315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at some examples, there are numerous ones out in the wild. The following is a great example for [twilio's](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-csharp) rest api; it leverages [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) under the covers. RestSharp is a great libary (available via nuget) to help out with the heavy lifting of interacting with a web api.

Note: Microsoft is coming out with a richer HttpClient option in .net 4.5; in fact, you can get it now via nuget.

Comment: RestSharp looks pretty good.  I will certainly take a look. Thanks.