# Google Maps handled server-side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

Learning from my broad question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086875/asp-net-page-lifecycle-and-events) ... I was wondering how I could go about using google-maps, server-side in c# ? Specifically, I need to use the distance-matrix-api and probably get and parse the results from JSON. If anyone could provide a basic outline of the structure needed to do this I would greatly appreciate it. (I have it worked out fine in javascript, but this created issues when I needed the distance data server-side.)

Comment: Maybe this answer can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side/7942315#7942315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a web service for the [Distance Matrix API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/). It works like the JS API but you just do a server side request and you can get JSON or XML results back.