# GetDynamicJsonObject exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, google-maps

I am trying to follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side/7942315#7942315) ...but get the exception:

'System.Uri' does not contain a definition for 'GetDynamicJsonObject' and no extension method 'GetDynamicJsonObject' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Uri' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have looked at every online example I can find but cannot figure out what am I missing here.

```
private void setTimeEstimates(ref List<Object> rides, string orig)
        {
            string dest, googleURL;
            dynamic googleResults;
            int driveTime; //in seconds

            using (myEntities = new RamRideOpsEntities())
            {
                foreach (Ride ride in rides)
                {
                    dest = interpretAddress(ride.PickupAddress);
                    googleURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json" +
                        "?origins=" + orig +
                        "&destinations=" + dest +
                        "&mode=driving&sensor=false";

                    googleResults = new Uri(googleURL).GetDynamicJsonObject(); //EXCEPTION HERE!

                    driveTime = googleResults.result.duration;

                    ride.EstTime = driveTime + BASE_WAIT_TIME;
                }
                myEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Some code would help, and it wouldn't hurt to point out which line the exception is happening on (or maybe a stack trace).

Comment: Sounds like you didn't grab the extension methods...  You might want to go back and look at the other links on that answer. or you didn't get the Newtonsoft json.net assembly and include it in your project

Comment: Aaah, yes you are right..I'm new to c# and visual studio, how do I add the extension methods? ...Just add a new class and stick the code in there?

Comment: Copy the code from the link directly into a new class file. Reference the `JsonUtils` namespace and you should be good to go.

Comment: Awesome gotta love the super easy fixes. Thanks!

Comment: One last quick question...when I reference the JsonUtils namespace, VisualStudio can't find it. Is there something I need to do to add the namespace? So far I just dumped the code into a new class in my project root and added 'using JsonUtils' to my other class.

Comment: That should be all you would need to do. As long as the code is in the same project and you didn't tamper with the `namespace` provided in the referenced code it should just work.

Comment: Ah, had to change the build action to 'compile' in properties. Hooray it works! ( :

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy fix: forgot to add JsonUtils extension methods