# How do I call a function to use in JavaScript?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get this piece of code to work in my C#.NET web application,
However I am unable to get the results into a label, let alone how to get the results in a piece of JavaScript for Google Maps.

I love this example which I am using.
[Google Maps v3 geocoding server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side)

But my "limited" knowledge of C#.NET won't allow me to figure it out :(
Thanks for reading!

Regards, Robert.

Comment: Are you trying to call a C# method using JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know how to use that code, I want to be able to return the lat+long to the JavaScript part