# How to Call JavaScript Function in Controller mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have one javascript function which is writted in view and i want call that function in Controller.the javascript takes input parameter and return one result. i have to store that value in string or variable.can anyone please help me in this.thanks in advance.here i mentioned my sample JavaScript here,

```
function GetLong(address) {

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


                long = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            } else {
                alert("Request failed.")
            }

        });

        return long;
    };
```

Comment: javascript is client side code. You cannot call it from a server. You can use ajax to send the value to a controller method (but its not clear what you want to do)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the MVC framework is to seperate Model, View and Controller. You can't invoke a javascript code from the MVC-Controller since the view is rendered and displayed in the client browser. You can invoke the javascript code in the view and send a POST or GET request to your Server for if you need a dynamic comunication between your view and controller.

If you want to use that javascript code in C# for example you might want to have a look at this https://github.com/jonsagara/geocodingapi

Or this Answer might be helpful aswell [Google Maps v3 geocoding server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942095/google-maps-v3-geocoding-server-side)